# how to pass a pipe() descriptor to Python subprocess.Popen(), in any version of Python

Tags: python, pipe

I want to spawn a child process in Python, whose standard streams are used for other purposes and I can't touch them, and I want to have a dedicated pipe for my own purposes, independent of standard streams.

In Python version 2, the following works:

`foobar.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from os import pipe, environ, read
import subprocess

output, input = pipe()
new_environ = environ.copy()
new_environ["PIPE_INPUT"] = str(input)
subprocess.Popen(['./a.out'], env=new_environ)
print(read(output, 6))
```

and `a.out` is compiled from `foobar.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    write(atoi(getenv("PIPE_INPUT")), "foobar", 6);
}
```

This works, `./foobar.py` prints `foobar`.

But, with the shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

it does not work.  Of course, this is because, according to the docs, in Python 3 the descriptors are not inheritable.

Well, then how do I do this in Python 3, and also so that the same code works for Python 2.  I cannot have different code for different Pythons, has to be portable code for Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Since 3.4 there is `os.set_inheritable` and for Windows `os.set_handle_inheritable`. Also you may have to set `close_fds=False` in the `subprocess.Popen` call.

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes but like I said, I cannot emit code that is not portable between 2 and 3, has to be portable Python.

Comment: Parameter `close_fds` already exists in Python 2. The `set_inheritable` call can be enclosed in `try`-`except AttributeError: pass`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher OK, I somehow missed `set_inheritable`, thank you.  Please make this into the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I have made an answer out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `input` descriptor inheritable if necessary, use

```
import os

try:
    os.set_inheritable(input, True)
except AttributeError:
    # This is Python 3.3 or older -> Nothing to do
    pass
```

The `Popen` call must then be modified to

```
subprocess.Popen(['./a.out'], env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
```

which works on Python 2 and Python 3.